# Can't display accents when executing a cpp code

Tags: c++, cmd, locale, iostream

For fun i coded a simple code in cpp using the Cesar's wheel to encrypt messages but i can't display accents and non ASCII characters while i used some wstring, wcin and wcout I also used the library locale to use the system encoding in the terminal opened by VScode and it works but not in the code i want.
My VScode is pre-configured by my school for cpp coding and it opens a Windows Terminal window to run the code.

Here is the code that display accent and non ASCII characters :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <locale>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        wcout << L"Texte avec accents : é, à, ô" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

In the actual code i want it to works it doesn't so i need help.
Here is the code i want to kdisplay non ASCII characters and it doesn't :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "game-tools.h"
    #include <locale>
    using namespace std;

    wstring messageACrypter;

    void demanderMessage(wstring &message);
    void encrypterLeMessage(wstring& message);
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        demanderMessage(messageACrypter);
        encrypterLeMessage(messageACrypter);
        return 0;
    }

    void demanderMessage(wstring &message)
    {
        wcout << "Quel est le message que vous voulez encrypter via le systeme de la roue de Cesar"    <<endl;
        wcin >> message;
    }
    void encrypterLeMessage(wstring &message)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        int memTemp;
        wstring memTempString;
        wstring messageCode;
        int nbrDeCryptage;
        nbrDeCryptage = random(1,26);
        for (int i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            memTemp = int(message[i])+nbrDeCryptage;
            memTempString=wchar_t(memTemp);
            messageCode+= memTempString;
        }
        wcout<<"Voici le message encrypte"<<endl;
        wcout<<messageCode;
    }
```

If you have any suggestions i'll take them and sorry i'm not that good in coding i'm in my first year in IT college

Comment: Your "encryption" is ASCII-based. It won't work well with international characters, especially if it happens to be using any of the non-ASCII Unicode encodings. Besides `int(message[i])+nbrDeCryptage` can result in characters outside of ASCII (even outside *extended* ASCII), and might not even be printable.

Comment: Unless the assignment requires international characters, I recommend you stay with old plain 7-bit ASCII. If you need international characters, or support for e.g. UTF-8, then a simple Caesar cipher is a *lot* more work. Libraries can help, but you still need to be able to handle non-contiguous characters and going outside of the selected character range for the locale.